# Are OpenSSH vs OpenSSL public key format names mismatched?

Tags: encryption, ssh, openssl, openssh

I generated a key pair vis OpenSSH and later wanted to generate PEM encoded public key.
I noticed that generated public key differs when generated by OpenSSH vs OpenSSL when using same format name (PEM)...
After some testing (see below), **I found that public keys are the *same* only when generated a) as PKCS8 in OpenSSH and b) as PEM in OpenSSL**

1. Why is PEM output of OpenSSH different than PEM format of
   OpenSSL?
2. If this is just a parameter naming mismatch, am I
   correct in my assumption that to get the same public key, I have to
   use PCKS8 in OpenSSH and PEM in OpenSSL?

Here is my test:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Using OpenSSH
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# generate test key pair 
[root@localhost key-test]# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f test.ssh

#
# get MD5 fingerprint of generated public key 
#
[root@localhost key-test]# cat test.ssh.pub | openssl md5 -c        
(stdin)= 3e:b6:6f:95:d2:1d:ca:7a:f3:88:2e:3a:ca:c3:b7:a3

#
# get MD5 fingerprint of generated public keys (RFC4716, PEM, and PKCS8 formats)  
#

# header => ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
[root@localhost key-test]# ssh-keygen -y -e -m RFC4716 -f test | openssl md5 -c
(stdin)= 0d:da:5b:27:e9:cd:32:25:e5:c8:4e:2b:c2:0f:47:aa

# header => -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
[root@localhost key-test]# ssh-keygen -y -e -m PEM -f test | openssl md5 -c       
(stdin)= c5:38:c0:41:f8:76:41:7b:49:03:42:c6:21:dd:1c:2f

# header => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
[root@localhost key-test]# ssh-keygen -y -e -m PKCS8 -f test | openssl md5 -c  
(stdin)= 84:e8:54:5f:16:9f:92:48:67:99:54:65:13:ad:64:ad


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Using OpenSSL
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#
# get MD5 fingerprint of the generated public key (PEM format)
#
# header => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
[root@localhost key-test]# openssl rsa -in test -pubout -outform PEM | openssl md5 -c            
(stdin)= 84:e8:54:5f:16:9f:92:48:67:99:54:65:13:ad:64:ad
```

Comment: When writing the *SubjectPublicKeyInfo*, which is the one with the pre-encapsulation header boundary of `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`, the keys should be the same. Inside, they are ASN.1/DER encoded sequences and bit strings (with additional PEM and Base64 encoding on top). The ASN.1/DER is effectively the pair `{Algorithm,Public Key}`, where the algorithm is a OID. The various public keys (`----BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY----`, `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`) encode the algorithm into the pre-encapsulated header boundary. SSH keys also use a triple that is `{Algortihm,Public Key,Email}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little step:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -e -m PKCS8 -f /home/wolf/.ssh/id_rsa | openssl asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING        

$ openssl rsa -in /home/wolf/.ssh/id_rsa -pubout -outform PEM | openssl asn1parse
writing RSA key
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING        

$ ssh-keygen -y -e -m PEM -f /home/wolf/.ssh/id_rsa | openssl asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001

$ openssl rsa -in /home/wolf/.ssh/id_rsa -RSAPublicKey_out -outform PEM | openssl asn1parse
writing RSA key
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001

$ ssh-keygen -y -e -m PKCS8 -f /home/wolf/.ssh/id_rsa | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | base64 -d | openssl asn1parse -inform DER -i -strparse 19
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons:  SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
```

The openssl [man page](https://openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html) calls one the PEM format and the other the RSAPublicKey format.

What `ssh-keygen` calls PKCS8 and `openssl rsa` calls PEM is a wrapper around what `ssh-keygen` calls PEM, that adds an [ASN.1 OID for "rsaEncryption"](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.1). The last example parses the DER bitstring that starts at offset 19 to convince ourselves that it's the same exact data.

The format is described in [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A).

PKCS#8 is [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208), and talks about storing private keys, not public keys.

I can't help answering what is the more correct name for each of the two formats, though I would call them by the ASCII string in the header.

I like the format that encodes the fact that it's an RSA public key inside of it, and so does not require externally encoding it (like the "ssh-rsa" prefix used in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`), though it is a little bigger. Using a self describing format, a program can learn to read ECDSA and EdDSA keys without inventing a new way to specify that the data is a public key but not an RSA public key.

Comment: As user29925 hinted, the generic format for a public key consisting of an AlgorithmIdentifier (in general not merely an OID) plus a BIT STRING containing the per-algorithm data, which ssh-keygen miscalls PKCS8, OpenSSL code calls PUBKEY, and Java crypto calls X.509, is `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` defined in X.509 and more conveniently available in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1 detailed in rfc3279 et rel